# How to disable past dates in GridViewDataDateColumn in aspxgridview

Tags: devexpress

```
<dx:GridViewDataDateColumn FieldName="ScheduledTimeForDelivery" Caption="Scheduled Time For Delivery" Width="14%" VisibleIndex="5">
                                        <Settings AutoFilterCondition="Contains" />

                                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Font-Bold="True" Wrap="True" />

                                        <PropertiesDateEdit  DisplayFormatString="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt" EditFormatString="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt">
                                            <TimeSectionProperties Visible="true">
                                                <TimeEditProperties EditFormatString="hh:mm tt" EditFormat="Custom"></TimeEditProperties>
                                            </TimeSectionProperties>

                                            <ValidationSettings RequiredField-IsRequired="true" ErrorTextPosition="Bottom" ErrorDisplayMode="Text">
                                                <RequiredField ErrorText="Please enter the Scheduled Time For Delivery" />
                                            </ValidationSettings>

                                        </PropertiesDateEdit>
                                        <EditFormSettings VisibleIndex="3" />
                                    </dx:GridViewDataDateColumn>
```

I want to disable all previous dates in my Column"ScheduledTimeForDelivery" how to disable it previous dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this line in cell editor initialize even

```
 if (e.Column.FieldName == "ScheduledTimeForDelivery")
                (e.Editor as ASPxDateEdit).MinDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reference:** [ASPxGridview - date column](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q518373)

Use the editor's `MaxDate` and `MinDate` properties for this purpose. For example:

```
GridViewDataDateColumn dateColumn = gridView.Columns["ScheduledTimeForDelivery"] as GridViewDataDateColumn;
dateColumn.PropertiesDateEdit.MaxDate = System.DateTime.Now.AddYears(5);
dateColumn.PropertiesDateEdit.MinDate = System.DateTime.Now.AddYears(-5);
```

Or you can manage to do it in aspx page also with help of documentation..

[Disabling specific dates in ASPxDateEdit, in Edit form of ASPxGridView](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q356090)

Hope this help..